# AWS CodeArtifact not adding npm packages to my repository

Tags: npm, dependencies, aws-codeartifact

The whole point of using something like CodeArtifact in my project was to manage 3rd-party npm and pypi dependencies, but it doesn't seem to work as expected with npm.

I've created in CodeArtifact a domain and a main repository called "MainRepo" with two upstreams stores: npm ("npm-store") and pipy ("pipy-store"). Then locally in my PC I've created a new folder and setup the connection using AWS CLI to "MainRepo" specifying npm as tool. After checking successfully that npm is now pointing to my repository with:

```
npm -d ping
```

I proceeded to install husky and commitlint:

```
npm install husky --save-dev
npm install @commitlint/cli --save-dev
```

At this point would expected to see those packages (and their dependencies) showing up in my main repository (or at least the npm-store) but to my surprise neither of them where listed. Then I've made a number of tests, installing other packages but not a single one got added.

Finally I've tried with:

```
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

and this was indeed added to my repo and showing up in the CodeArtifact console.

Any clues on why the others packages got ignored by CodeArtifact?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, in my case I was testing with an existing project which already had a `package-lock.json`. This file has a `resolved` field for each dependency which makes the installer to look up in those registries even if you changed your main registry in your computer.

My solution was to delete the `package-lock.json` for it to be created again with the registry pointing to CodeArtifact. Once I installed my packages again, I was able to see all packages in my repo.